# Given $n > m$ and $0 < p < 1$, is it true that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} > \sum_{k=1}^{m}{m \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{m-k} $?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, combinations

Suppose $n > m$ and $0 < p < 1$. Is it true that

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} > \sum_{k=1}^{m}{m \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{m-k} $$

I looked at couple of examples, and seems like it holds. But now I wish to have more general proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_{r=0}^n (_r^n)p^r(1-p)^{n-r}=(p+1-p)^n=1$$

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n (_r^n)p^r(1-p)^{n-r}=1-(1-p)^n$$

for n>m $$ (1-p)^n <(1-p)^m$$

$$ \Rightarrow 1-(1-p)^n >1-(1-p)^m$$

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n (_k^n)p^r(1-p)^{n-r}>\sum_{k=1}^m (_k^m)p^r(1-p)^{m-r}$$

Comment: @layman Thank you

Comment: @Mathmerizing Thanks for the answer. One more question: if we let $k=x$, where $1 < x ≤ n$, will the proposition hold too? (You've shown that it holds when $k=1$)

Comment: @Nelver the result won't hold for all the values of k as in $C(n,x)(1-p)^xp^{n-x}$ , C(n,x) will increase and then decrease and also now we need to consider this function $(1-p)^xp^{n-x} $along with binomial coefficient. So the result will vary for different values of k